I get error after installation of laravel through HERD
I have installed laravel using HERD but when i go http://127.0.0.1:8000/ to view the installation i get the below error. I have tried to use both mysql and sqlite. It seems to me as though a table has to be created but none is created during installation which is generating the error. Could anyone help me?
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: sessions 
(Connection: sqlite, SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = KfAiiHfNPAtyOCWD5xsQRCEtiF8TGwbUVXvyKfLv limit 1)


Since you're using the database driver to handle sessions, you might need to generate the migrations and run them
php artisan sessions:table

php artisan migrate


thanks for the comment, it solved my issue
